Heroku deployment fails due to OpenAI module import issues in Node.js/TypeScript project
I'm experiencing issues deploying my Node.js/TypeScript application to Heroku. The deployment fails with errors related to importing the OpenAI module. Below are the details of the problem and the steps I've taken so far.
Problem Description:
I'm working on deploying a Node.js/TypeScript backend service to Heroku. The backend service uses the OpenAI module for some of its functionalities. However, the deployment fails with errors related to module imports from the OpenAI package.
Here are the error messages from the Heroku deployment logs:
src/controllers/userController.ts(4,10): error TS2614: Module '"openai"' has no exported member 'Configuration'. Did you mean to use 'import Configuration from "openai"' instead?
src/controllers/userController.ts(4,25): error TS2724: '"openai"' has no exported member named 'OpenAIApi'. Did you mean 'OpenAI'?
src/controllers/userController.ts(5,15): error TS2614: Module '"openai"' has no exported member 'ChatCompletionRequestMessage'. Did you mean to use 'import ChatCompletionRequestMessage from "openai"' instead?
src/controllers/userController.ts(5,45): error TS2614: Module '"openai"' has no exported member 'ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum'. Did you mean to use 'import ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum from "openai"' instead?

**What I've Tried:
**Updated package.json dependencies:
I ensured that the openai package is up-to-date in my package.json:
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "openai": "^4.51.0",
  ...
}

Modified import statements in userController.ts:
I've tried several variations of the import statements to resolve the errors:
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import type { ChatCompletionRequestMessage, ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum } from "openai";


Ensured TypeScript configuration:
My tsconfig.json is set up to handle module resolution properly:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    ...
  },
  ...
}

Added build scripts to package.json:
Added the necessary build scripts for Heroku:
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "tsc",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm install --only=dev && npm install -g typescript && npm run build"
}

What I Expected:
I expected the deployment to complete successfully, allowing my backend service to be up and running on Heroku.
What Happened Instead:
Despite these changes, the deployment continues to fail with the same module import errors.
